# Django on delete cascade not producing the right constraint in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, foreign-keys, cascade

In Django, I have a model:

```
class HmmInsectValue(models.Model):
    hmm = models.ForeignKey('HmmResult', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

on a PostgreSQL database (9.3.2) this produces a constraint:

```
FOREIGN KEY (hmm_id) REFERENCES devdash_hmmresult(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

while what I really want is:

```
FOREIGN KEY (hmm_id) REFERENCES devdash_hmmresult(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This breaks my code because when I try to delete an `HmmResult` entry it complains that it's is still referenced from `HmmInsectValue`. If I replace it manually with the line above it all works fine.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 9):

Because Django simulates the on_delete clause in the application tier. I believe it does this so it can still provide things like delete signals and the like.

The `on_delete` attribute of `ForeignKey` instructs Django what to do, it does not translate directly into the database construction statements.

See Also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DO_NOTHING